# Docker: any way to list open sockets inside a running docker container?

Tags: docker, netstat, alpine-linux

I would like to execute netstat inside a running docker container to see open TCP sockets and their statuses. But, on some of my docker containers, netstat is not available. Is there any way to get open sockets (and their statuses, and which IP addresses they are connected to if any) without using netstat, via some docker API? (BTW, my container uses docker-proxy - that is, not directly bridged)

I guess I could look at /proc file system directly, but at that point, I might as well docker cp netstat into the container and execute it. I was wondering if there was any facility that docker might provide for this.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You can use the `nsenter` command to run a command on your host inside the network namespace of the Docker container.  Just get the PID of your Docker container:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container_name_or_id
```

For example, on my system:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' c70b53d98466
15652
```

And once you have the PID, use that as the argument to the target (`-t`) option of `nsenter`.  For example, to run `netstat` inside the container network namespace:

```
$ sudo nsenter -t 15652 -n netstat
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Notice that this worked even though the container does not have `netstat` installed:

```
$ docker exec -it c70b53d98466 netstat
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"netstat\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
```

(`nsenter` is part of the `util-linux` package)

Comment: Does this solution applicable for other platforms such as windows, mac etc.,?

Comment: @Rao, possibly: `nsenter` is a Linux command, so you would need to be able to log in to the Linux VM that is actually being used to host your Docker containers.  And of course, that VM would need to have the `nsenter` command available.

Comment: you may use this snippet to get all netstat for all dockers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171909/when-using-docker-established-connections-dont-appear-in-netstat/49296022#49296022

Comment: On an AWS EKS node, I'm root, but get: `sudo nsenter -t 14207 -n netstat` returns
`nsenter: cannot open /proc/14207/ns/net: No such file or directory`.  I can see the path that it says does not exist but cannot seem to do anything to interrogate it.  Has anyone run into this?

Comment: `nsenter` => *Permission denied*
`sudo nsenter` => *bash: sudo: command not found*

Comment: @marc If you're running on Linux it looks like you will need to either install and configure `sudo` or figure out another way to run commands as `root` (if you're not running on Linux then this answer won't be appropriate).

Comment: I'm in a linux container (nginx image). I think it doesn't run as root, no tools are installed so almost no diagnosis is possible.

Comment: You run `nsenter` on your *host*, not inside the container.

Answer (score 48):

The two commands from @larsks answer merged into one-liner - no need to copy-paste the PID(s) (just replace `container_name_or_id`):

```
sudo nsenter -t $(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container_name_or_id) -n netstat
```

Comment: Sidenote: one would need to add another `sudo` so that the command is `... $(sudo docker inspect ...`, otherwise the command will fail if it isn't run in a root shell.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `iproute2` package installed, you can use

```
sudo nsenter -t $(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container_name_or_id) -n ss
```

or

```
sudo nsenter -t $(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' container_name_or_id) -n ss -ltu
```

It will show `TCP` and `UDP`

Answer (score 4):

If you want them all (all containers) try this.

```
$ for i in `docker ps -q` ; do sudo nsenter -t $(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' $i) -n netstat ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other solutions and it didn't work for me by my colleague gave me this solution.  Thought I would mention it here for others like me and for me to refer to later lol.

docker exec -it [container name] bash

grep -v “rem_address” /proc/net/tcp

Comment: i just tried that, it outputs `  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode \n                                                     
   0: 0B00007F:ABD3 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 479599 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0`

Answer (score -1):

docker inspect <container_id>

- Look for "ExposedPorts" in "Config"

Comment: Does this actually show ports *in use*, or is it just a list of exposed ports that the container can listen on?

Answer (score -3):

> server:docker container ls

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS           PORTS       NAMES

80acfa804b59    admirito/gsad:10   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 10 minutes    80/tcp      gvmcontainers_gsad_1
```

Comment: this is wrong. this will only five you the ports that either the Dockerimage declared and those that were explicitly exposed (in both cases it doesn't matter if the container process is actually listening...)