# How to check if a port is open in a docker container with python/nodejs script?

Tags: python, node.js, docker

I have a docker container A. There are two applications ( B&C) running in the container A in Ports 8080 and 8081( TCP ports). I would like to write a python/nodejs or bash script to check if ports are open by respective applications?

Usecase:

1. Get Hostname of the docker container
2. Validate if both applications A and B opens the port to Ports 8080 and 8081.
3. Once validated, i need to print that test has passed and print exit status.

Comment: Many docker users use this bash script for the same https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

Comment: can you precise how the ports are use for the connections (e.g a protocol) ?

Comment: Sure, it's TCP ports

Comment: Checkout this post,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350456/docker-any-way-to-list-open-sockets-inside-a-running-docker-container

Answer (score 0):

You can use [netstat](https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) to display open ports. Together with [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) you can filter the output like this:

```
netstat | grep 8080
```

netstat's output will be directed to grep, which only displays lines containing "8080"
You can then use [test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) to check that both netstat commands output something, for example by using -n (meaning a string is nonzero):

```
#!/bin/bash
servicea=$(netstat | grep 8080)
serviceb=$(netstat | grep 8081)

if [ -n "$servicea" ] && [ -n "$serviceb" ]
then
echo "up and running"
fi
```

Note: This works from inside the container. To access ports from outside the container you need to [map them](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/).